# Logging into Windows VDI from Ubuntu - aka equivalent app of "Remote Desktop"

Tags: vdi

Is there a way to log into the Windows VDI (running on Azure) using an app like "Remote Desktop" on Windows? Currently, I can logging in using the Web page (https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient), but as a result, I would not have access to my microphone and webcam on my computer.

The "official" way is using Web or "Remote Desktop" from Windows. Is there any workaround for this?

Official Microsoft documents:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/connect-windows-7-and-10

Comment: Assuming your client is Ubuntu, you can use `viangre` (a remote desktop client for the GNOME Desktop)

Comment: Can't Remina do that?

Comment: There are fully-supported RDP and VNC clients and servers in the Ubuntu repositories for remoting. These are not "workarounds," but longstanding daily-use cross-platform solutions. Your Azure system must run an appropriate RDP or VNC server (that's the hard part), and your local system must use a compatible client.  Both vinagre and reminna are examples of such clients in the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the webclient url for VDI!
https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient

From what I understand, even if you have the ability to connect through this webclient to the VDI, you might still have issues due to security hardening. In case of a typical rdp situation like with rdesktop tool, you would connect to the server but in some cases it will be the reverse (i.e. Reverse Proxy). Therefore, you would get:

> Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser, app, or location that is restricted by your admin.

```
More details
...
Device identifier: Not available
Device platform:
Device state: Unregistered
```

If you face this issue than my solution would be to install all the fancy windows apps to confirm your device identity (following 2FA etc., AD procedures) in a windows VM inside of your Linux host and then, you would connect to it through the Remote Desktop windows app.

Setup:

Linux host -> Windows VM with Remote Desktop -> VDI / WVI (Windows Virtual Desktop)